# How can I access to the insights data of global pages from root page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how can I access to the insights data of differents global pages from root page (global pages).

I tried with graph API explorer, but it only returns the root page id.

Also, I've been searching for it in different docs but I only have found this link with information about the Global Pages structure.

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/331800410323820[image]

It is assumed that you can obtain data of all global pages from root page using API Facebook but I haven't found the way to do it.

Thank in advance.